# Import data from Excel to SQL Server using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net

I am importing data from Excel into a SQL Server database using vb.net. In my Excel file, in column `bNumber`, there are values of different types i.e some are numbers and some are text:

```
Telenorx
Telenorx
8
97150219924
97150219924
97150219924
97150219924
Easypayx
92
```

When I select the data from Excel through `OleDbCommand`, it retrieves numbers correctly but text values as blank.

In Excel, the column's data type is `General`.

This is my code to retrieve data from Excel.

```
excelConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source= " + OpenFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 
Xml;HDR=Yes""")
Dim oleDbCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select bNumber from 
[Sheet1$]", excelConn)
excelConn.open()
Dim dataReader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader 
dataReader.read()
```

Comment: What is your SQL Datatype ?

Comment: Can you provide some details of what you are doing here? How are you querying the data? Give us something.

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, you should post said code. It's impossible to help except to say that you have a bug somewhere

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a solution for your case yet would I did was created a SQL-Server table with bNumber as nvarchar, used SQL-Server Management Studio to export to Excel where I placed the Excel file in the bin\Debug folder of the project. Using the code below all rows returned properly (as we have a string column strings are returned).

The key here is using IMEX=1 in the connection string, Excel can be finicky, this may or may not resolve the issue.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Operations
    Public Function GetData(ByVal FileName As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim valueList As New List(Of String)
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection With
            {
                .ConnectionString = ConnectionString(FileName)
            }
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT bNumber FROM [Table_1$]", cn)
                cn.Open()
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read
                    valueList.Add(reader.GetString(0))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
        Return valueList
    End Function
    Public Function ConnectionString(ByVal FileName As String) As String
        Dim Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
        If IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToUpper = ".XLS" Then
            Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
            Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes;")
        Else
            Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
            Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes;")
        End If

        Builder.DataSource = FileName

        Return Builder.ConnectionString

    End Function
End Class
```

Form code

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles Button3.Click

    Dim ops As New Operations
    Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Downloaded.xlsx")
    Dim valueList As List(Of String) = ops.GetData(fileName)
    For Each value As String In valueList
        Console.WriteLine(value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Results in the IDE Output window

[image]

Table structure

[image]

Worksheet

[image]

EDIT: The following link points to a MSDN code sample for working with SpreadSheetLight library. Once downloaded, set startup form to StackOverFlow1QuestionMixedTypesForm. Right click on the solution in solution explorer and select "Restore NuGet Packages", now build and run the project. There are two buttons on the form, first does mixed types for Sheet1 while button two is a variant of the same data laid out differently in Sheet2.

Code sample https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Alternate-methods-to-work-4c52c4a2

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and concern.  you just type the values in excel which i provided but this is not the case. My problem is in excel file because the column type is 'General'. if i select the data as it as then my  query is unable to retrieve 'Text' as General and if i change the column type to 'Text' then all data can be fetched but numbers become like this.               9.23495E+11,
9.23495E+11,
9.23494E+11.   Also i don't want users to bother about changing excel column type.

Comment: If open to an alternate method, there is a free library that might be helpful called SpreadSheetLight. This library offers more freedom when reading Excel data. Downside is all examples are in C# on their site yet this week created a code sample on MSDN that shows the majority of common operations and to boot, this morning created an example that would give you a running start that I can append to my first reply, just let me know (it's in VB.NET)

Comment: yes why not, I will appreciate it and i can also code in c#. Just keep it in consideration that my excel files have more then one columns of different data types and i don't want the user of my app to change the column' s data type because i think it will be inconvenient for user to open excel file, change the data type of column and then come to my app and upload the file. it is also to be noted that i m receiving excel files from outside and app user has just to select the file and upload data.

Comment: Just updated my reply, refer to the last section of my reply.